# Combinatorics Issue with Long Expression

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, combinations, random

So I have this strange issue that I'm not sure how to resolve. If x, y, and z are randomly chosen integers from a set {1, 2, 3... 2016} and I need the probability that $6z - 3yz + xyz - 4xy + 8x + 12y - 2xz$ is divisible by seven. This should be written in a fractional form. How should I go about this? Thank you!

Comment: what does "is divisible by seven is written in a fractional form" mean?

Comment: The probability that the above expression is divisible by 7. The probability is written in a a/b.

Comment: Can you give the source for this problem?  Presumably it's some old contest from 2016?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $2016 = 288 \times 7$.

**Hint:** $6z - 3yz + xyz - 4xy + 8x + 12y - 2xz = (x-  3)(y-  2 )(z-  4 ) + 24$.

> Fix $y-2, z-4$.
>  If either of these $ \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$, then there are no solutions for $x$.
>  If they are both non-zero, then there are 288 solutions in $x$. (Do you see why?)

Hence, the probability is $288 \times ( 6 \times 288) \times ( 6 \times 288) / 2016^3 = \frac{36}{343}$

Comment: The 2nd Hint is the key to this problem.  If it were just a generic polynomial, is there any systemic way to answer the question (besides listing all $7^3$ possibilities)?

Comment: Well, both hints are needed to do the final calculation. If the expression is linear in $x$, then we're looking at $f(y,z)x + g(y,z)$. Likewise, for a fixed $(y,z)$ such that $f(y,z) \neq 0 \pmod{7}$, there is a unique $x \pmod{7}$ solution, otherwise there are 0/7 solutions. Then it remains to calculate when $f(y,z) \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$.

Comment: Ah, good point.  If at least one variable is linear then it simplifies quite a bit already.  However, it might be non-trivial to calculate when $f(y,z) = 0$, and further, among those $(y,z)$ which makes $f=0$, we need to further classify them by whether $g=0$ (any $x$ works) or $g\neq 0$ (no $x$ solution).  Depending on $f,g$ this can be very complicated...

Comment: Yea, esp for competition problems, the idea is to simplify/factorize it as much as you can. In this case, the factorization is easily observed. However, they could have been cruel and given the expression as $xyz +3xy+4yz+5xz+x-2y-z$ (equivalent mod 7), and it's then hard to see the factorization or guess what it should be. In this case, viewing it as $x (yz+3y+5z+1)+(4yz-2y-z) = x(y+3)(y+5)+(4yz-2y-z)$ will allow us to make significant headway.

Comment: Yeah, I hate it when a competition problem is tedious and requires a lot of grunt work, but not soooo tedious that you are _sure_ you're missing a clever factorization.  :)